# Can I restrict access to a Google Cloud SQL instance to specific service account?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

I have multiple environments in Google Compute Engine (dev, staging, and production), each with its own Google Cloud SQL instance. The instances [connect via Cloud SQL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy) and authenticate with a credential file that is tied to a service account. I want to have a separate service account for each environment, which would be restricted to accessing the SQL instance specific to that environment. Currently, it appears that *any* service account with role `Cloud SQL Client` can access *any* Cloud SQL instance within the same project.

I cannot find any way to restrict access on a Cloud SQL Instance to a specific service account. Is it possible, and if so, how? If not, is there a different way to achieve the goal of preventing a server in one environment from accessing a Cloud SQL instance in another environment?

NOTE: this configuration is possible with Google Cloud Storage; one can assign a specific service account to have various permissions on each bucket, so that the dev service account cannot accidentally access Production files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the [August 2021 release of Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#August_21_2021):

> You can use IAM Conditions to define and enforce conditional, attribute-based access control for Google Cloud resources, including Cloud SQL instances

See the [documentation for IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control#iam-conditions) for information about how to restrict a user or service account to specific Cloud SQL instances.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, Cloud SQL currently does not support instance level IAM policies.

The only workaround is hosting the instances in different projects.

Comment: Thank you. Managing multiple projects for the same application seems like it might introduce other problems. Is there a way to request instance-level IAM polices for Cloud SQL?

Comment: You can submit feature requests on the Cloud SQL issue tracker: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still the case?

Comment: @jreptak you can follow the status here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68765990

Comment: I originally accepted this answer, but with the latest release of Google Cloud SQL, you can use conditional IAM to restrict access, as described in the new accepted answer.